# Parse JSON to XML

Tags: json, xml, xml-parsing, rss

I parse json to xml and get the result as below, but the xml feed is not showing the result in my server. Could anyone check and give me some ideas? I need XML result showing on my dashboard. Here is actual URL (http://imodelicon.com/pinkertan/test/convertjson.xml)

I also edit XML script into RSS format, but there is no content at all afterward.

Thanks,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<root>
-<data>
<message>This summer both Stephen Curry & Kevin Durant toured Asia,   
connecting with fans & inspiring young athletes.  »    
http://on.nba.com/2bWpo3L  » http://on.nba.com/29LfO6X</message>

<story>Golden State Warriors added 4 new photos.</story>

<created_time>2016-09-15T01:03:28+0000</created_time>

<id>47657117525_10154616463827526</id>

</data>
-<data>

<message>The worlds of sports & tech came together once again as Stephen   
Curry attended TechCrunch Disrupt in San Francisco. #TCDisrupt</message>

<created_time>2016-09-14T23:21:38+0000</created_time>

<id>47657117525_10154616220367526</id>

</data>
-<data>

<message>All Summer 16. #DubNation</message>

<created_time>2016-09-14T18:42:15+0000</created_time>

<id>47657117525_10154615411837526</id>

</data>
-<data>

<message></message>

<story>Golden State Warriors shared Draymond Green's photo.</story>

<created_time>2016-09-14T18:29:31+0000</created_time>

<id>47657117525_10154615388222526</id>

</data>
-<data>

<message>Single game tickets are now available for Warriors Insiders! »    
http://on.nba.com/17O7eLP</message>

<created_time>2016-09-14T17:10:00+0000</created_time>

<id>47657117525_10154613058837526</id>

</data>
-<data>

<message>Signs that training camp is almost here... </message>

<story>Golden State Warriors added 2 new photos.</story>

<created_time>2016-09-14T01:41:40+0000</created_time>

<id>47657117525_10154613158592526</id>

</data>

-<paging>
<previous>https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/47657117525/feed?
access_token.......</previous>
<next>https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/47657117525/feed?   
 access_token=......</next>
</paging>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are extraneous `-` characters before each tag on the second level as well as before the `root` element.

While the former are not a problem (except maybe from a validation perspective), the latter makes the document not well-formed, because text is not allowed outside of the document element.

Comment: Sorry, it maybe a typo. When you check the link, the extraneous "-" is actually gone. Any other suggestions?